# Joomla syntax for mysql last inserted id?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

What is the joomla syntax for mysql last inserted id?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just `$db->insertid();` Ensure you call it immediately after the insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

Get db connection

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
```

Create a new query object.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

Query to insert data

```
$query->insert('tablename')->columns('columnname')->values('custom msg');
```

Reset the query using newly populated query object.

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Execute the query

```
$db->execute();
$lastinsertid = $db->insertid(); // last insert id
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code so the asker could understand your answer more easily